# Avoid adding FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK when required screen is already displaying

Tags: android, firebase

I'm receiving a push notification and need to show MyScreen on notification click. But right now, I'm already aware, that I'm showing MyScreen. So, instead of notification, I'm just sending an Intent and handling in on MyScreen in onNewIntent method.
This works fine for Android 7- (API 27-). For API 28 I have to add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` when creating a new Intent in MyFirebaseMessagingService.

Is there any easy way not to recreate MyScreen in such a scenario? I mean, not adding `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` but doing something else to call onNewIntent instead.

Comment: You could add a static boolean like isMyScreenRunning, which is updated in the onStart and onStop of the MyScreen. Then, before creating the intent check this boolean to see if you need to add this flag

Comment: I already know this information. 
For Android 8+ we need to add FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag always, if create Intent from the Service.